# NullReferenceException in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, nullreferenceexception

I've created a PartialView and here's how I'm calling it.

```
<div id="bodyarea">
    <div id="leftnavigationbar">     
        @Html.Partial("_SideBarMenu")
    </div>

    <div id="mainbody">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the actual code for the PartialView:

```
@model Cumavi.ViewModels.SidebarNavigation

<ul>
    @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
    {
        <li>category.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

As you can see, I'm using a custom created ViewModel called SidebarNavigation, which has this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Cumavi.Models;

namespace Cumavi.ViewModels
{
    public class SidebarNavigation
    {
        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; private set; }

        public SidebarNavigation()
        {
            CategoryRepository categoryRepo = new CategoryRepository();
            this.Categories = categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I run the application, I get a null reference exception on the foreach loop.

I don't understand the reason though. In the ViewModel, SidebarNavigation, in the constructor I'm actually filling the variable. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Another thing I've noticed is that the constructor for my ViewModel class is never actually called. :S That must be why the Categories attribute is null. Suggestions?

**Edit 2:**

Another problem! I'm using _Layout.cshtml file to create the common look (masterpage) for the application. Since no controller is associated to this file, how can I pass a model to it? :S

Comment: and you're sure the Exceptions is on the line @foreach (var category in Model.Categories) and not on  <li>category.Name</li> ?

Comment: @Pauli: Yep, 110% sure that it's on the foreach line. Thanks for the help, really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 3):

You're not passing the model through to the partial view.

```
@Html.Partial("_SideBarMenu")
```

All that does is render a partial view called **_SideBarMenu.cshtml**

But your partial view expects: `Cumavi.ViewModels.SidebarNavigation`

Pass through the model:

```
@Html.Partial("_SideBarMenu", model)
```

Also - why do you have a ctor for **SidebarNavigation** where you populate the categories?

Your controller should instantiate that viewmodel:

```
var model = new SideBarNavigational { Categories = repository.GetSomething() };
return View (model);
```

You should *never* make calls to your repository via your view models.

Comment: That makes complete sense, but now I'm back to square one. :P Where do I get that model from? I imagine from the Controller but the entire point of using a PartialView was to be able to call this from everywhere without repeating the model loading on every controller. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding your edit: Where would I write that code? I don't want to repeat that category fetching in every single controller. That seems to be the only way though. :\

Comment: Partial Views are use to *re-use HTML*, not *re-use the model*. Your partial view should *accept* a model (which it does). That model comes from the view which contains the partial. And that view gets the model from the controller. It should always flow that way. Controller -> Gets Model -> Passes to View -> View Renders Partial and Passes Model -> Partial Renders HTML with Model.

Comment: I understand that concept. So you're saying I have no choice but to call the repository in every single controller and method? Remember this is the menu that will be displayed in every page.

Comment: Create a base controller class that all other controllers inherit from.  That will allow you to keep all the navigation logic in one place.

Comment: @Serg.  You can also create an ActionFilter that updates the ViewModel, adding to it as necessary.  That ActionFilter can apply to all Controllers/Actions or some subset of them.

Comment: Yep - use either @AUSteve or @Hightechrider's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

remove your private accessor

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Are you sure that **categoryRepo.FindAllCategories();** returns not null?

Comment: It's strange, the constructor is never actually called, according to my breakpoint. I don't know why. To clarify, that line of FindAllCategories is never called.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario (if I understand it correctly) you should use `Html.Action` instead of `Html.Partial` and create a new action decorated with `ChildActionOnlyAttribute`. As mentioned in a comment to a different answer, partials are meant for reusable markup. For reusable data+markup you can use child actions.

For example you can create a `SharedController` class:

```
public class SharedController : Controller
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ViewResult SideBar() {
        return new PartialView(new SideBarModel());
    }
}
```

And then have a `SideBar.cshtml` view:

```
@model SideBarModel
.... Render contents here
```

And then from your `_Layout.cshtml` file you call:

```
@Html.Action("SideBar", "Shared")
```